# Polymorphism in Clojure

Tags: data-structures, object, clojure, oop, polymorphism

Suppose I have a bunch of Clojure data structures, all of the same type - for example an object type defined by defrecord.

What is the best way to get polymorphic behaviour across these structures?

Would it be good practice to embed a function within the structure so that I can do something like:

```
((:my-method my-object) param1 param2)
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use multimethods for dispatch,

```
(derive ::subtype ::type)
```

then you can dispatch based on type

```
(defmulti my-method
  (fn [type] ((meta type) :type)))

(defmethod my-method ::subtype []
  ;;stuff...
 )
```

You need to add :type to the objects metadata when you create it,

```
(with-meta [1 2 3] {:type ::subtype})
```

or I haven't tried this but since protocols and records creates java classes behind the scenes you dispatch based on that name.

Comment: Note: `(fn [type] ((meta type) :type))` is just called [`type`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/branch-1.1.x/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/type).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, protocols are what you want to use.

```
user=> (defprotocol P (foo [p x]))
P
user=> (defrecord R [a b] P (foo [_ x] [a b x]))
user.R
user=> (defrecord S [a b] P (foo [_ x] [x b a]))
user.S
user=> (def r (R. 1 2))
#'user/r
user=> (def s (S. 1 2))
#'user/s
user=> (foo r 3)
[1 2 3]
user=> (foo s 3)
[3 2 1]
```

In the above both `R` and `S` implements the `foo` function defined by protocol `P`, but they each do so differently.  When the `foo` function is called, it dispatches on type of the first arg.

Comment: I'm using protocols/defrecord already - the point is that I want polymorphic behaviour between objects of the same type (i.e. multiple instances of R in your example)

Comment: Then you want probably multimethods. `(defmulti foo (fn [R-instance] (if (= :full (:phase-of-moon R-instance)) :do-this :do-that)) (defmethod foo :do-this ...) ...`